# Issue with page load timeout and next task is directly sent to except

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, multiprocessing

I was running a python script responsible for web scraping some pages using multiprocessing techniques.

In order to wait for a page to get fully loaded, I used the method `set_page_load_timeout()` set to 30s.

I put a `driver.get()` inside a try-except structure.

However, I observed that in my case, when all the 5 Chrome instances are busy with 5 different pages,  the next page pulled from the task queue goes to my exception and stored in my error file. I presume this occurs since the Chrome instances are still trying to load the 5 previous pages and not able to redirect to this new page.

How could I get over this issue?

Comment: You don't want to use Selenium this way. Run them in separate processes or switch to Pyppeteer.